# iOS Unit Tests: simulate Home Button press etc

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, automated-tests, gh-unit

is it possible to simulate pressing Home Button to terminate app in the automated tests? Is it possible to simulate switching to AirPlane Mode?
I am using GHUnit and I want to test these scenarios:

1. Press Home button during file download and wake the app again
2. Switch to AirPlane mode during download (or simply turn on AirPlane mode)
3. Switch from WiFi/3G to EDGE
4. Simulate memory-warning
5. Simulate incoming call when connected to EDGE

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working with a test framework called Frank.
From the items you listed you can simulate the following with Frank:

1. Press Home button
2. Simulate memory warning.

Frank is an acceptance test framework to the users interaction with the application.
You can find it [here](https://github.com/moredip/Frank).

For your other scenario's I can't think of a way you could test it with the simulator.
I think that is more important for you to know which events are triggered when such a scenario occurs. You then maybe use the Frank framework to simulate such events.

Comment: Thank you, it will satisfy my needs :)